# How to fix synchronous url loading abd Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)?

Tags: swift, dataframe, csv, asynchronous, runtime-error

I am trying to make my app that uses data from csv files. I made a class for a city, but I get an error whenever I call one of the city class functions in my `ContentView()`. When I click the submit button, `getStats()` runs with the input value from the submit button and is supposed to retrieve data from csvs based off of that.
However, it gives me the error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

at the line

```swift
let state: String = new["state", String.self][0] ?? "There was an error"
```

I think that this may be due to the fact I do not know how to access a link asynchronously. The last message in my terminal is

> Synchronous URL loading of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shadowdragon2805/CrimeData/main/docs/csv/crime_data_w_population_and_crime_rate.csv should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

How would I go about switching to asynchronous loading, and is this the actual problem? Is synchronous loading known to cause

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Thank you!

The `getStats` function(where the error occurs):

```swift
func getStats(input: String) -> DataFrame.Slice{

    let columns = ["zip", "primary_city", "state", "county", "latitude", "longitude"]
    let statsColumns = ["county_name","crime_rate_per_100000","CPOPARST","CPOPCRIM", "MURDER","RAPE","ROBBERY","AGASSLT","BURGLRY","LARCENY","MVTHEFT","ARSON","population"
    ]
    do{
        let convert1 = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shadowdragon2805/CrimeData/main/docs/csv/zip_code_database.csv")!, columns: columns, types: ["zip": .string, "primary_city": .string, "state": .string, "county": .string, "latitude": .double, "longitude": .double])
        
        convert = convert1
        
    }catch{
        Swift.print("Convert Error")
    }
    
    do{
        let stats1 = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shadowdragon2805/CrimeData/main/docs/csv/crime_data_w_population_and_crime_rate.csv")!, columns: statsColumns)
       
        stats = stats1
    }catch{
        Swift.print("Stats Error")
    }
    

    convert.combineColumns("latitude", "longitude", into: "location") { (latitude: Double?, longitude: Double?) -> CLLocation? in
        guard let latitude = latitude, let longitude = longitude else{
            return nil
        }
        return CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }//combine columns
    
    let new = convert.filter(on: "zip", String.self){$0 == input}//find zip code
    let state: String = new["state", String.self][0] ?? "There was an error"//find state
    let loc: CLLocation = new["location", CLLocation.self][0]!
    location = loc//use later

    let county = new.rows[0][3, String.self]
    let countyStats = stats.filter(on: "county_name", String.self){$0 == (county ?? "error") + ", " + state}//what I want
    return countyStats//return my stats
}
```

How I call the function(in contentview):

```
func submit() {
    print("The city/county/zip inputted: \(input)")
    
    let stringStats = test.getStats(input: input.zip)
    print(stringStats)
    resignKeyboard()
}
```

Comment: OK, the “Synchronous URL loading” error undoubtedly rests inside `DataFrame`, where it probably is loading from that URL using something synchronous like `Data(contentsOf:)`. Like the error says, you should download it asynchronously with `URLSession`, and then pass the downloaded contents to `DataFrame`. It's hard to be more specific without more info about this `DataFrame` type you reference.

Comment: Regarding the `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`/`EXC_I386_INVOP` problem with that line, it looks like you are using some non-standard subscript operator, but assuming that is valid, I would replace `new["state", String.self][0] ?? ...` with  `new["state", String.self].first ?? ...` or something like that. If the array is empty, the `[0]` syntax with crash, whereas `first` says “get me the first value, and return `nil` if empty”. On both this point and my prior one, it's hard to say without details about all these types you are using. There is no there is not enough here to diagnose your issues.

Comment: @Rob Thank you so much, the subscript works now! I'll also implement the URL soon. :)